# Títulos alternativos para los breadcrumbs en sphinx

Tags: cms, documentbuilder

En la documentación de sphinx se dice que en el doctree se puede especificar un nombre diferente al título del documento para los items del menú de navegación:

```
.. toctree::

intro
All about strings <strings>
datatypes
```

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

En este ejemplo,en el menú de navegación, aparecerá "All about strings" en vez del título definido en "strings.rst".

Mi consulta es: ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que este "título alternativo" se use también en los breadcrumbs en vez del título del documento?

Buceando por los los archivos del tema que estoy usando ("sphinx_rtd_theme") encuentro esto, que es la linea que genera los items de los breadcrumbs:

```
{% for doc in parents %}
<li><a href="{{ doc.link|e }}">{{ doc.title }}</a> &raquo;</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Entiendo que para conseguir el comportamiento que busco, se debe usar un atributo distinto a "title" en el elemento "doc", pero ¿cual?